# Exclude specific vhost/domain from certbot

Tags: certbot

When I run certbot, I get a list of all my vhosts/domains. I need HTTPS for all of them, except one: api.mydomain.de. Is it possible to get certificates for all domains from apache, except a certain one, so that I dont have to enter each specific domain?

Comment: You could disable that one from your apache config for the 2 minutes it takes to run certbot. The renew command (usually run on cron) only cares about which sites you have certs for, so it would ignore the one that has no cert.

Comment: That does not work. The disabled vhost is still listed in certbot